# How to represent NaN in array of numbers?

Tags: java, nan

The question says it all. I have an  array of doubles and am doing something with them.

```
double expectedOutput[] = { 6.38792, 12.91079, 14.33333, 13.44517,
                12.34539, 12.05397, 8.34061, 2.07900, -2.01999, -5.47802,
                -8.21610, -9.26719, -11.02378 };
```

Ideally, i would test to see if

`6.38792 == 6.38792` and end up with a 'pass'

Under certain conditions, i end up with the situation like

```
6.38792 != NaN
```

Knowing that this is a valid case sometimes, how can i represent NaN in my code?

I either need to include `NaNs` into my array of expected elements or somehow figure out that result is Not A Number

I am using **Java**

Comment: Java. I'll update the question

Comment: Double.NaN? testing NaN x==x (ensures it's not a NaN), Double.isNaN() and so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, you can get NaN by using

```
Double.NaN
```

So you can just put this into your array.

If your question is how to check if something is NaN, you can call

```
Double.isNan(/* ... value ... */);
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to test for it explicitly, since `NaN != NaN`, you can't just include it in your array. You have to use `Double.isNaN(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 0.0/0.0;
if(Double.isNan(d)){
    // Double d is not a number.
}
```

Alternatively:

```
double d = Double.Nan;
if(Double.isNan(d)){
    // Double d is not a number.
}
```

Comment: -1 NaN will never compare equal to NaN (or any other number).

Comment: Fixed. "Fail" was unecessary.

Comment: Undid the downvote because you fixed your answer, but still no cookie for you. :-D

Comment: Heh, no you didn't. Someone else did upvote though, so thanks to that person.

Comment: @TheBigO: Actually, I _did_ undo the downvote. (But I did not upvote you. Two users originally downvoted you; I retracted one of them.) OTOH, I just noticed that someone decided to serial-downvote my posts. If that's you, be aware that this can cause all your votes to be cancelled: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young, if that's true, then sorry about that. I was just interpreting the activity that SO displayed to me, as I saw it. And no, I didn't "serial-downvote" you, if you like I can provide a screenshot of my recent activity. I'd be surprised if SO didn't prevent malicious downvoting and fraudulent upvoting. Either way, you have the freedom to vote as you see fit -- otherwise voting wouldn't work.

Comment: @TheBigO: I'm glad that got cleared up! :-) Also, I believe you on the serial-downvoting thing. In any case, I couldn't care less, because I have way more rep than people can make a dent on before the system catches them. :-) (On the other hand, there was recently a rep recalc performed on my account (apparently triggered by the serial-downvoting), which docked me ~500 points. Ouch!)

Answer (score 0):

Since in many languages NaN is not equal to itself (and in Java also), you should handle it as a specific case. Use Float.NaN or Double.NaN to reference NaN. Use Float.isNaN or Double.isNaN to check if a specific value is NaN.

Comment: "many languages" should be "all IEEE-754 compliant languages" :)

Comment: I'm still looking for "The IEEE quick reference citation book" to use it in social evenings ;) - thanks for the reference anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where `Double` objects actually are more useful than primitive `double`s.

```
// auto-boxes them all to Double objects
Collection<Double> expectedOutput =
    Arrays.asList(6.38792, 12.91079, 14.33333, 13.44517, 12.34539,
                  12.05397, 8.34061, 2.07900, -2.01999, -5.47802,
                  -8.21610, -9.26719, -11.02378, Double.NaN );
// maybe fill into HashSet for more efficient lookup?

// later:
double d = Double.NaN;
if(expectedOutput.contains(d)) {
    System.out.println("found");
}
```

The reason is that `Double.equals` in fact implements the reflexivity condition of the equals contract, meaning that `Double.valueOf(Double.NaN).equals(Double.valueOf(Double.NaN))` gives `true`, contrary to `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`.